# when condition with loop expression in scala spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to translate a pyspark solution into scala.

Here is the code:

```
conditions_ = [when(df1[c]!=df2[c], lit(c)).otherwise("") for c in df1.columns if c not in ['firstname','middlename','lastname']]

status = when(df1["id"].isNull(), lit("added"))
             .when(df2["id"].isNull(), lit("deleted"))
             .when(size(array_remove(array(*conditions_), "")) > 0, lit("updated"))
             .otherwise("unchanged")
```

for scala, I am simply trying to use expr instead of * to substitute the conditions_ expression in my when clause, but it is not supported due to for syntax.

Can you please point me to the right syntax here to add a loop in when clause, calculating the count of column differences dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unpack array in scala you can use following syntax:

```scala
when(size(array_remove(array(conditions_:_*), "")) > 0, lit("updated"))
```

[Examples of "_*" operator](https://www.lorrin.org/blog/2011/10/04/scalas-missing-splat-operator/)